# Building REST Java API on existing PHP server

Tags: java, php, rest, web-services, api

In a recent academic project I need to create some REST Java API (web service) that works on an existing PHP server.
I don't have much clear ideas on how to implement it. How would you implement the logic? Is it okay to send a request (Ajax) to the web service, which it then forwards it to the PHP server?
How would you implement it?

Thank you for your advises!

Answer (score 0):

Java REST service could call PHP REST service. If REST service on php side not implemented, we can use some html robot for acting like a http client from java. HtmlUnit or Selenium for example.

Comment: so basically should I make CRUD operations to the existing PHP server, retrieving the results and return them with web service, right?

Comment: yes, you could use some rest calling library, for example spring RestTemplate, or simple apache HttpClient.